# Proving Delta Sifting Distributionally

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Starting with the delta distribution:

$ \langle\delta, \varphi\rangle = \varphi(0)$, where $\varphi \in D(\varphi)$ is a test function

This establishes the "sifting property" for test functions but I want to understand how we can extend this to all continuous functions, $f \in C[\mathbb{R}]$ not necessarily a smooth function, as represented in Dirac notation as $\int_R \delta(x)f(x) dx = f(0) $.

So the question is, how does one arrive at the same result using distributions?

Comment: $\langle \delta f, \varphi \rangle = f(0)$ is not true.

Comment: I edited the question for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any distribution $u$ with compact support can be extended to all of $C^\infty$. This is done by taking $\rho \in C_c^\infty$ such that $\rho \equiv 1$ on a neighborhood of the support of $u$ and for $\phi \in C^\infty$ setting
$$\langle u, \varphi \rangle := \langle u, \rho\varphi \rangle.$$

This is well-defined since two such $\rho$ will only differ outside of the support of $u$.

---

**EDIT**

How can we apply $\delta$ on a function $\varphi$ that is only continuous?

Let $\psi \in C_c^\infty$ be a [mollifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier), i.e. $\psi_\epsilon(x) := \epsilon^{-1}\psi(x/\epsilon) \to \delta(x)$ as $\epsilon\to 0$.

Now,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi_\epsilon(x) \, \varphi(x) \, dx
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \epsilon^{-1} \psi(x/\epsilon) \, \varphi(x) \, dx
= \{ x=\epsilon y \}
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi(y) \, \varphi(\epsilon y) \, dy \\
\to \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi(y) \, \varphi(0) \, dy
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi(y) \, dy \, \varphi(0)
= \varphi(0).
$$
Thus we can define $\langle \delta, \varphi \rangle := \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int \psi_\epsilon(x) \, \varphi(x) \, dx = \varphi(0).$

Comment: Ok, great thanks that makes complete sense -- the mollifier approach is how was thinking about it at first, albeit incorrectly.

Comment: Question: can we also do this using a support argument like you made previously? Namely, if $f \in C^{\infty}$ and $\varphi \in D$ is a test function, then the $f\varphi$ is a test function too since $supp(f\varphi) = supp(\varphi)$. And so $\langle f\delta, \varphi \rangle = \langle \delta, f\varphi \rangle = f(0)\varphi(0)$. Then by the picking a test function which has support in a neighborhood of $0$ such that $\varphi=1$ we recover the desired expression. To relax the smooth requirement, we note that since $supp(\delta) = \{0\}$, $f$ merely needs to be continuous at $0$. Is this accurate?

Comment: @a9120bb. First a small correction: $\operatorname{supp}(f\varphi) \subseteq \operatorname{supp}(\varphi)$ since it can happen that $f=0$ on some subset of $\operatorname{supp}(\varphi)$.

Comment: @a9120bb. On an intuitive level your argument might work. But it should be remembered that the action of a compact distribution is only defined for $C^\infty$ functions, so we need to do something with our $C^0$ function to make it $C^\infty$ and then show that $C^0$ is indeed enough. A better way than what I did is probably to use the convolution $\psi_\epsilon*\varphi$ which is $C^\infty$ and show that $\langle \delta, \psi_\epsilon*\varphi \rangle \to \varphi(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

As @md2perpe notes, every compactly-supported distribution on $\mathbb R^n$ extends to an element of the dual space of the space of smooth functions on $\mathbb R^n$.

In fact, if we pay attention to the Frechet space (projective limit) topology on the space of all smooth functions, we can show that the dual is *exactly* compactly-supported distributions.

But this seems not to be exactly the question you're asking. You appear to be asking how to legitimately and uniquely extend Dirac $\delta$, arising as an element of the dual space to test functions, to an element of the dual space to the Frechet space of continuous functions $C^0(\mathbb R^n)$. And, indeed, again looking at the Frechet space (projective limit) topology on $C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$, and using a definition of *order* of a distribution, we find that all $0$-order compactly-supported distributions give (continuous) linear functionals on $C^0(\mathbb R^n)$.

Comment: Generally, if $u$ has compact support and is of order $k$ then we can apply $u$ on $C^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$. We lose differentiability however.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Paul. I apparently don't have enough points to give it an upvote.